# Component Calling Action only works with direct import

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have an Action, its mapped with connect :

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {hideTenantDialog, updateUserInformation })(TenantComponent);
```

I call the updateUserInformation within a button.
The Error is:

i import it directly from the file where the action is in (authentication/authActions.js)
the authentication component itself has a index.js where I import all from actions and export it again

here is the code from the index.js :

```
import authReducer from './authReducer';
import { showLogin, fetchProfile, logoutCurrentUser, updateUserInformation } from './authActions';
import { getBearerToken  } from './bearerToken';

export {
    authReducer as AuthReducer,
    showLogin as ShowLoginAction,
    fetchProfile as FetchProfileAction,
    logoutCurrentUser as LogoutAction,
    getBearerToken as GetAuthenticationHeaderToken,
    updateUserInformation
}
```

so: when I import the updateUserInformation from (authentication/actions.js) everything works
when I import it from (authentication/index.js) the function is not mapped to props.

any ideas ?

The Repo for better understanding is here : [GITHUB Ahrimaan](https://github.com/Ahrimaan/MettAppReact)

EDIT
authActions.js ->

```
import {
    CURRENT_USER,
    LOGIN_FAILURE,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_WITH_GOOGLE,
    LOGOUT,
    LOGIN_PROCCESING,
    USERINFORMATION_UPDATED,
    USERINFORMATION_UPDATED_FAILED,
    USERINFORMATION_UPDATING
} from './actionTypes';
import { showTenantDialog, hideTenantDialog } from '../tenant';
import { getCurrentProfile, login, logout, updateUser } from './authenticationService';
import { HIDE_TENANT_DIALOG } from '../tenant/actionTypes';

export function showLogin() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_PROCCESING });
        login().then(result => {
            if (!result.user.tenant) {
                dispatch(showTenantDialog());
            }
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: result.user });
        }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: err });
        })
    }
}

export function updateUserInformation(tenantId) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type:USERINFORMATION_UPDATING})
        let action = updateUser(tenantId).then(result => {
            /* dispatch({
                type:USERINFORMATION_UPDATED,
                payload:result
            }); */
            // Find a better way, the component itself should track if a tenant switch is needed
            dispatch({type:HIDE_TENANT_DIALOG})
        }).catch(err => {
            // globalerror
            dispatch({type:USERINFORMATION_UPDATED_FAILED});
        })
        dispatch(action);
    }
}

export function fetchProfile() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let profile = getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile) {
            if (!profile.tenant) {
                dispatch(showTenantDialog());
            }
            dispatch({ type: CURRENT_USER, payload: profile });
        }

    }
}

export function logoutCurrentUser() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        logout();
        dispatch({ type: LOGOUT })
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you import from `authentication/index.js`

Comment: import { updateUserInformation} from '../authentication'

Comment: Your post says the file is authentication/actions.js when you import directly but your index.js code says to import from authActions. Seems to be a disconnect there or you're missing some important information in your post.

Comment: @AdamKipnis sorry typo, edited my error

Comment: Can you add your export in authActions as well?

Comment: @AdamKipnis Edikte the code for you, the original Code can be found in my repo : https://github.com/Ahrimaan/MettAppReact